# Screen tears getting caught in various places

Tags: gala, screenshot

I've been experiencing a problem with OBS recently, as it was adding horrible screen tearing to videos in certain applications.

[Here's a video example.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfOev4G0WOg)

However today I took a screenshot, and I caught a very similar screen tear in that screenshot.

[Screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/6Bs7ITs.png)

Any ideas what might be causing this? These tears are invisible, but are driving me up the wall when it comes to recording videos.